# Checking a list for items with some conditions

Tags: python, list, data-science

I have a function which return a list of two items as below

```
student_score = my_class.calculation()
student_score = [50.0, 70.0]
```

On some cases the student score returns None and the student_score returns the list [None, None] but i would like to check for my list if the values are None the student_score values should be changed to defualt values of [10.0, 20.0]

I have tried the below, which works well but i would like to make it into a list comprehension.

```
val = [None, None]

for i in val:
    if val[0]== None and val[1]==None:
        val[0] = 10.0
        val[1] = 20.0
```

Comment: `if not any(val): val = [10.0,20.0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I have a solution making use of a list comprehension. Also, I don't understand why you're looping over `val`. Here it is:

```
val = [None, None]
if all(elem is None for elem in val):
    val[0] = 10.0
    val[1] = 20.0
```